# Cannot find save handler - redis cluster

Tags: php, redis, centos, cluster-computing, phpredis

I'm using phpredis (redis_cluster branch) with redis stable (v3.0.4) on top of CentOS 7.1 (latest) and PHP 5.6 (remi repo) with Apache (2.4.6)

Using cluster with 3 masters (test only).

My redis.ini contains:

```
extension = redis.so
session.save_handler = rediscluster
session.save_path = "mycluster[]=192.168.1.100:6379&mycluster[]=192.168.1.100:6380&mycluster[]=192.168.1.100:6381&timeout=3&read_timeout=3&failover=error"
redis.clusters.seeds = "mycluster[]=192.168.1.100:6379&mycluster[]=192.168.1.100:6380&mycluster[]=192.168.1.100:6381"
redis.clusters.timeout = "mycluster=5"
redis.clusters.read_timeout = "mycluster=10"
```

Simulating a simple store session with PHP on redis (cluster):

one.php:

```
session_start ();
$_SESSION['favcolor'] = 'green';
$_SESSION['animal'] = 'cat';
$_SESSION['time'] = time();
```

two.php:

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Got this on apache errors:

```
PHP Warning: session_start(): Cannot find save handler 'rediscluster' - session startup failed in /var/www/html/one.php on line 4
```

Any ideas out there what might be the problem ?

Answer (score -1):

Remove the trailing slash from the save_path ;)